# Python-pptx: issue with insert_picture() function - 'sha1' AttributeError

Tags: python, python-2.7

I am trying to write a basic script to update a PowerPoint (2016) presentation, template.pptx, which contains predefined place holders for images. I am running into issues with the insert_picture() function.

As an example, the 4th slide of template.pptx contains a Picture Placeholder:

```
from pptx import Presentation

prs = Presentation('template.pptx')

slide4 = prs.slides[3]

for shape in slide4.placeholders:
    print('%d %s' % (shape.placeholder_format.idx, shape.name))
```

which gives the following output

```
>>> 
0 Title 3
10 Picture Placeholder 7
```

I proceed with

```
placeholder = slide4.placeholders[10] # idx key, not position
picture = placeholder.insert_picture('test.jpg')
```

Which throws the following error(s):

```
File "C:\Python273\lib\site-packages\pptx\shapes\placeholder.py", line 323, in insert_picture
pic = self._new_placeholder_pic(image_file)
 File "C:\Python273\lib\site-packages\pptx\shapes\placeholder.py", line 334, in _new_placeholder_pic
rId, desc, image_size = self._get_or_add_image(image_file)
 File "C:\Python273\lib\site-packages\pptx\shapes\placeholder.py", line 345, in _get_or_add_image
image_part, rId = self.part.get_or_add_image_part(image_file)
 File "C:\Python273\lib\site-packages\pptx\parts\slide.py", line 42, in get_or_add_image_part
image_part = self._package.get_or_add_image_part(image_file)
 File "C:\Python273\lib\site-packages\pptx\package.py", line 50, in get_or_add_image_part
return self._image_parts.get_or_add_image_part(image_file)
 File "C:\Python273\lib\site-packages\pptx\package.py", line 159, in get_or_add_image_part
image_part = self._find_by_sha1(image.sha1)
 File "C:\Python273\lib\site-packages\pptx\package.py", line 171, in _find_by_sha1
if image_part.sha1 == sha1:
AttributeError: 'Part' object has no attribute 'sha1'
```

I have seen this 'sha1' error mentioned in these forums but don't fully understand it (I am a bit of a novice).

Interestingly (frustratingly), I don't run into this issue when creating a PowerPoint from scratch (as per the example in the python-pptx 0.6.7 docs):

```
prs = Presentation()
slide = prs.slides.add_slide(prs.slide_layouts[8])
placeholder = slide.placeholders[1]  # idx key, not position
picture = placeholder.insert_picture('test.jpg')
prs.save('new.pptx')
```

This runs fine, hence I am left very confused. Any help would be much appreciated. Thanks!

(Windows 7, Python 2.7.3)

Comment: have you solved? I have the same issue...

Answer (score 2):

I have found a possible cause for this problem! For me the problem was that the presentation contained images that were not in either jpg, png or gif. It was a tif file. For these files, theres is no sha1 and therefore the script throws an exception. Converting/deleting these files made the problem disappear!

Please tell me if that fixes it for you too.

Comment: I had same problem and solved after removing scalar vector graphics (SVG) images.